# How can I limit each item in a ListView to one line?

Tags: java, android, xml

In a ListView populated by an ArrayList, how can I limit the number of characters per list item or limit each list item to only one line of text?  It's a notes app. all my code is below.

ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static ArrayList<String> note;
ListView listView;
static ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
static  Set<String> set;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    setTitle("Notely");
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {





            notes.add("");

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypackage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            if (set == null) {

                set = new HashSet<String>();

            } else {

                set.clear();

            }

            set.addAll(notes);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("notes").apply();
            sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).apply();

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditNote.class);
            i.putExtra("noteId", notes.size() - 1);
            startActivity(i);






        }
    });


    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("mypackage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    set = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("notes", null);

    notes.clear();

    if (set != null) {

        notes.addAll(set);

    } else {

        notes.add("Example note");
        set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.addAll(notes);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).apply();

    }


    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditNote.class);
            i.putExtra("noteId", position);
            startActivity(i);


        }

    });



    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                    .setMessage("Do you want to delete this note?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            notes.remove(position);

                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("mypackage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            if (set == null) {

                                set = new HashSet<String>();

                            } else {

                                set.clear();

                            }

                            set.addAll(notes);
                            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("notes").apply();
                            sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).apply();
                            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();

            return true;
        }
    });



}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

EditNote.java

```
public class EditNote extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher{
int noteId;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_note);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    setTitle("Write a Note");



    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    noteId = i.getIntExtra("noteId", -1);

    if (noteId != -1) {

        editText.setText(MainActivity.notes.get(noteId));


    }

    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {



    MainActivity.notes.set(noteId, String.valueOf(s));
    MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypackage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (MainActivity.set == null) {

        MainActivity.set = new HashSet<String>();

    } else {

        MainActivity.set.clear();

    }


    MainActivity.set.addAll(MainActivity.notes);
    sharedPreferences.edit().remove("notes").apply();
    sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", MainActivity.set).apply();


}


@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
}
```

Comment: Set `maxLines="1"` and `ellipsize="end"`

Comment: I tried that in the ListView's xml.   It didn't work though.

Comment: Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: What layout are you using for your item's layout?

Comment: @felix Not on the `ListView` but to the `TextView` of your list item.

Comment: I'm talking about the layout used by your adapter. Could you show us your adapter code?

Comment: I just added both my .java files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using a built-in layout (`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`) for each item in your `List View`. It sounds like you want to customize this. So you need to create your own layout with a `<TextView>` with appropriate attributes, including

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: I made an xml file called liststyle.xml containing a TextView with those attributes.  When I try to use it in android.R.layout.liststyle, android studio  does not recognize it

Comment: @felix Try `R.layout.liststyle`. The `android` at the beginning attempts to use the `R` class from the `android` package which is built in to the API. You need to use the `R` class from your own project instead.

Comment: Thanks, the error goes away.  But when I test it, the app crashes upon switching activities.  Is something wrong with my liststyle.xml?  It is posted below.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: @felix This is a new issue. Please post a new question.

Comment: ok i got it.  i had to remove the linerlayout.  Thanks for all your help!  ill still post a new question, just so the answer's out there for other people.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the maxLines to one and ellipsize to end is not going to work when you apply those settings to the ListView itself. Instead, you have a layout you are inflating for your ListView items. I am assuming that it contains a TextView since you want to have a single line with ellipsis instead of a TextView whose content grows vertically. Add these lines to the TextView within your List item layout. Again, this layout is the one you are inflating for each ListView item.

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

You will then use this layout to create your adapter. Also note that you call `setAdapter()` twice, which is unnecessary.

Comment: I just posted all my code.  I don't have a TextView, so how would I do this?